# Unity suddenly broken

Tags: unity

All of a sudden, Unity is broken on Ubuntu 14.04.
After the logging screen, I can see the desktop but there are no unity panel and no top taskbar.

I tried to boot in recovery mode but I can't access the menu by holding "shift" or "esc" from boot.

How can I repair Unity ?

Note : on guest session, Unity is working.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :

from Ubuntu destop, press **Ctrl+Alt+F2**, you will swith to a TTY teminal.
Enter your user name and password.
type : `DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal` this opens a terminal in your Ubuntu desktop.
Return to Ubuntu destop by pressing **Ctrl+Alt+F7**.
Type in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools

dconf reset -f /org/compiz/

setsid unity
```

then reboot.